# Backgrounded IOS app wakeup by Push notification and exchange data with another ios device using core bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, apple-push-notifications, core-bluetooth

I am developing the app where app can behave as both Central and Peripheral in foreground and background. That is working fine by using state preservation and restoration.

Now the next requirement is like both app (Central & Peripheral) are nearby but should connect automatically only when there is push notification fired from backend.

So as soon as push notification arrive, app should wake up, Start advertising as Peripheral and Central look for peripheral with fixed service UUID.

I tried to initialise both peripheral and central role on app wakeup by push notification but it never get connect with each other and exchange data.

So question is how can i achieve this waking up app by Push notification and then connect with other iphone's peripheral and other iphone's central to current iphone and exchange data.

Here i am trying to wake up app when notification arrives :

> func application(_ application: UIApplication,
> didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable:
> Any],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping
> (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
> {
>
> ```
>     localPeripheralManager = PeripheralManager(delegate: self)
>     localCentralmanager = CentrallManager(delegate: self)
>   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
> }
> ```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So question is how can i achieve this waking up app by Push notification and then connect with other iphone's peripheral and other iphone's central to current iphone and exchange data.

Comment: @ElTomato - did you get my question, let me know if you need more detail. I tried every possible way but its way far to success.

Comment: It sound to me that you have phone A which acts as a peripheral and phone B which acts as central. When a push notification arrives, B starts scanning and A starts advertising. Once B discovers A, a connection is triggered, is this scenario correct?